# Pinch Zoom on Android with an embedded ScrollView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, pinchzoom

I have an Android app with an Activity that I'd like to be able to pinch zoom.

The Activity is a LinearLayout that contains several controls, one of which is a ScrollView. I've implemented the zooming by following the very good example here:

https://github.com/Xjasz/AndroidZoomableViewGroup/blob/master/ZoomListView.java

Here's what I've seen:

- If I put Finger1 outside of the ScrollView, I can put Finger2 anywhere and things zoom beautifully.
- If I put Finger1 inside of the ScrollView, then nothing will zoom regardless of where I put Finger2.

It seems to me that once a finger goes into the ScrollView, the onTouchEvent is not propagated up to the parents.

Has anyone else seen behavior like this? Any ideas on how I can fix this so that I can always zoom if I touch inside the ScrollView first?

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).

Comment: I don't really see how this will help. This code looks very specific to ImageView and there are no ImageViews in my project.